# DialogFlow: Missing "user" property in JSON after successful Google Account linking

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

So after successful [Google Account linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50062639/dialogflow-actions-allow-google-assistant-user-to-create-event-in-google-calend) in my app, I tested it using an Android device without any problem. I used the "[in conversation prompt](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking#during_the_conversation)" technique to request the user to authenticate to proceed further. In other words, I was successfully able to receive the "user" property of response from Dialogflow with valid accessToken (among other info).

Now, I tried it on a Google Home device. The device is configured with the same email Id I used on the Android mobile device. The G.Home successfully loads the app when I invoke it. But the missing part here is the accessToken in the user property (JSON below). I have assumed the following in the above scenario:

1. Since I have already signed in successfully on the Android mobile device, the next time I try to invoke the app on the same device, the app doesn't prompts for the "sign in" because it already has the accessToken (until it is expired). And since I am using the same gmail address on the G. Home device, I should have gotten the same accessToken as well.
2. As long as the same gmail address is used, it doesn't matter what device/surface I use to Google auth myself, I will always get the accessToken if it has not expired.

The setup/configuration for the whole Google Account linking is detailed in the above link I've shared. Here is the JSON I've received on G. Home and Android device respectively:

```
{
  "originalRequest": {
    "source": "google",
    "version": "2",
    "data": {
      "isInSandbox": true,
      "surface": {
        "capabilities": [
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
          }
        ]
      },
      "inputs": [
        {
          "rawInputs": [
            {
              "query": "continue",
              "inputType": "VOICE"
            }
          ],
          "arguments": [
            {
              "rawText": "continue",
              "textValue": "continue",
              "name": "text"
            }
          ],
          "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
        }
      ],
      "user": {
        "lastSeen": "2018-07-17T10:33:57Z",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "userId": "15229245xxx"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "conversationId": "153182806xxx",
        "type": "ACTIVE",
        "conversationToken": "[\"disclaimer_option\"]"
      },
      "availableSurfaces": [
        {
          "capabilities": [
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
            },
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
            },
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "id": "9459d297-4746-4ffe-99fa-xxx",
  "timestamp": "2018-07-17T11:49:02.693Z",
  "lang": "en-us",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "continue",
    "speech": "",
    "action": "v00.authentication.pin",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
      "CallEnum": "Login"
    },
    "contexts": [
      {
        "name": "disclaimer_option",
        "parameters": {
          "CallEnum": "Login",
          "CallEnum.original": ""
        },
        "lifespan": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "pin",
        "parameters": {
          "CallEnum": "Login",
          "CallEnum.original": ""
        },
        "lifespan": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "google_assistant_input_type_voice",
        "parameters": {
          "CallEnum": "Login",
          "CallEnum.original": ""
        },
        "lifespan": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "actions_capability_audio_output",
        "parameters": {
          "CallEnum": "Login",
          "CallEnum.original": ""
        },
        "lifespan": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "actions_capability_media_response_audio",
        "parameters": {
          "CallEnum": "Login",
          "CallEnum.original": ""
        },
        "lifespan": 0
      }
    ],
    "metadata": {
      "intentName": "v00.authentication.pin",
      "isResponseToSlotfilling": false,
      "intentId": "146f0d7d-0194-43cb-90e4-xxx",
      "webhookUsed": "true",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "nluResponseTime": 87
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "",
      "messages": []
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success"
  },
  "sessionId": "15318280xxx"
}
```

and

```
{
  "originalRequest": {
    "source": "google",
    "version": "2",
    "data": {
      "isInSandbox": true,
      "surface": {
        "capabilities": [
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
          }
        ]
      },
      "inputs": [
        {
          "rawInputs": [
            {
              "query": "Continue",
              "inputType": "TOUCH"
            }
          ],
          "arguments": [
            {
              "rawText": "Continue",
              "textValue": "Continue",
              "name": "text"
            }
          ],
          "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
        }
      ],
      "user": {
        "lastSeen": "2018-07-17T09:44:08Z",
        "accessToken": "6IlPNz0YFb_stP0quM1xxx",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "userId": "15229245xxx"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "conversationId": "153182082xxx",
        "type": "ACTIVE",
        "conversationToken": "[\"disclaimer_option\"]"
      },
      "availableSurfaces": [
        {
          "capabilities": [
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
            },
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
            },
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "id": "ae2e3ff8-f351-497b-9429-xxx",
  "timestamp": "2018-07-17T09:47:54.999Z",
  "lang": "en-us",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "Continue",
    "speech": "",
    "action": "v00.authentication.pin",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
      "CallEnum": "Login"
    },
    "contexts": [
      {
        "name": "google_assistant_input_type_touch",
        "parameters": {
          "CallEnum": "Login",
          "CallEnum.original": ""
        },
        "lifespan": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "pin",
        "parameters": {
          "CallEnum": "Login",
          "CallEnum.original": ""
        },
        "lifespan": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "disclaimer_option",
        "parameters": {
          "CallEnum": "Login",
          "CallEnum.original": ""
        },
        "lifespan": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "actions_capability_screen_output",
        "parameters": {
          "CallEnum": "Login",
          "CallEnum.original": ""
        },
        "lifespan": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "actions_capability_audio_output",
        "parameters": {
          "CallEnum": "Login",
          "CallEnum.original": ""
        },
        "lifespan": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "actions_capability_media_response_audio",
        "parameters": {
          "CallEnum": "Login",
          "CallEnum.original": ""
        },
        "lifespan": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "actions_capability_web_browser",
        "parameters": {
          "CallEnum": "Login",
          "CallEnum.original": ""
        },
        "lifespan": 0
      }
    ],
    "metadata": {
      "intentName": "v00.authentication.pin",
      "isResponseToSlotfilling": false,
      "intentId": "146f0d7d-0194-43cb-90e4-xxx",
      "webhookUsed": "true",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "nluResponseTime": 87
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "",
      "messages": []
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success"
  },
  "sessionId": "153182082xxx"
}
```

My question is, where can I get the `accessToken` when I am using the Google Home device?